# Stopwatch in React Native

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to make a stopwatch in React Native with milliseconds?

If so, can I ask you for help in this matter? Maybe some blog link or code snippet.

If not, what are the obstacles? Rendering?

Comment: In order to post better questions, it is helpful for yourself and others if you have a go at solving the problem yourself first. When you run into specific problems that you can't solve, even with the help of google and other answers on stackoverflow, then it makes sense to ask people here for help. You will learn more this way, and the community can devote time to answering questions of people who really need help and have already tried to help themselves.

Comment: @DevNet did my answer help you or not ? would be good if you could provide a feedback at least or accept my answer if u follwed the yt tutorial for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just googled "programming a stopwatch in react native" and the first hit was a youtube video and the second one was a article about your needs check them out maybe it can help you.

1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWegskGYCtA

2: https://reactnativecode.com/create-stopwatch-timer/

Comment: Link number 1 is inappropriate because it only shows minutes and seconds. Link number 2 is ok